# Why is the for loop not creating a instance in roblox studio?

Tags: roblox

I made a script that creates a mesh in every part but its not working?
And it randomly offsets the mesh
I have tried using print debugging (like `print("Created Mesh")` and `print("Offsetting..")`) but it prints it out with no problem (the code still doesn't work.)
I tried changing the code but it outputs the same results.
Here is the code.

```
for i, v in pairs(workspace:GetDescendants()) do
if v.ClassName == string.match(v.ClassName, "Part") then
    local mesh = Instance.new("SpecialMesh",v)
    mesh.MeshType = Enum.MeshType.Brick
    while true do
        for i = 0,math.random(0,5) do
            mesh.Offset = Vector3.new(math.random(-100,100)*.01,math.random(-100,100)*.01,math.random(-100,100)*.01)
            wait(0.1)
        end
        wait(math.random(10,30)*.1)
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The internal while-loop has no exit case, so the first object that it creates will block the original for-loop forever.

If you want to animate the mesh, I would recommend that you move the while-loop logic into a Script that is inside the mesh. This makes it so that every Script is able to work in parallel and not block the original for-loop that creates the meshes.

So create a Script and put it somewhere like `ReplicatedStorage`, and name it something like `AnimationScript`.

```
-- in ReplicatedStorage.AnimationScript...
local function getValue()
    return math.random(-100, 100) * 0.01
end

local mesh = script.Parent
while script.Parent ~= nil do
    for i = 0, math.random(0, 5) do
        mesh.Offset = Vector3.new(getValue(), getValue(), getValue())
        wait(0.1)
    end
    wait(math.random(10, 30) * 0.1)
end
```

Then, clone that Script into every mesh you create. This way, the loop isn't blocked and the animation is handled in a different script thread.

```
-- create a brick template
local mesh = Instance.new("SpecialMesh")
mesh.MeshType = Enum.MeshType.Brick
local animationScript = game.ReplicatedStorage.AnimationScript:Clone()
animationScript.Parent = mesh

-- put meshes inside all parts
for _, part in pairs(workspace:GetDescendants()) do
    if part:IsA("BasePart") then
        local brickMesh = mesh:Clone()
        brickMesh.Parent = part
    end
end
```